# Full Calendar get date from selected Week

Tags: jquery, web, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar plugin(week view) for jQuery in my project. In FullCalendar week view, I can see a row showing the date in following format:-
Sunday 9/6, Monday 9/7, Tuesday 9/8 so on...

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    defaultView: 'basicWeek'                    
});
```

Now I have used only header format in calendar for time sheet project. I want to get dates 9/6, 9/7 from current selected week in alert when move to next/previous week (this is for store date in database). It is possible to get dates separately for current week?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the begin & end dates from fullcalendar like this:

```
let currentDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
let beginOfWeek = currentDate.startOf('week');
let endOfWeek = currentDate.endOf('week');
```

**Edit:**

You can add the `events` configuration for fullcalendar. This way you will get the start & end dates when switching views and it also lets you fetch events and render them on the calendar.

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {
  // request the back-end and call the callback when the ajax is done
  $.get('events/get', function(result) {
    callback(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply A1rPun. I tried the above one. I get values in alerts for both values. I want to get weekdates when the user moves to next/previous week. means when the user move to next or previous week i want to get week dates from start to end

Comment: @user2396558 I've added a better approach to fit your needs (I hope). Made an example with pseudocode

Comment: Hi @A1rPun Thanks It's working now. I can able to get dates when move to next/previous dates